# PHP Websocket receiving incomplete data

Tags: php, websocket

I have the following code to receive data with a websocket.

```
$bytes=socket_recv($socket,$buffer2,1024,0);
$datarec=unmask($buffer2);
//process further
```

This works but many time I get incomplete messages and I am unable to process the data further.

I have come up with following solution.

Basically I reserve the first 10 digits for length of the data and before sending it using socket.send from javascript I add the length of the data at start of message. So if my message is "hello this is a message" it becomes "30:sizehello this is a message" I compensate for the added "30:size".

On the php side I hope to do this

First read the 10 digits.

```
$length=socket_recv($socket,$buffer2,1024,MSG_WAITALL);
```

and then use something like

```
$datarec=aocket_recv($socket,$buffer2,$length,MSG_WAITALL);
```

Sadly, this does not work as I am unable to read and unmask the data received with socket_recv 2nd time.

Any suggestions on how to make sure you get complete data from websocket without knowing the data length before hand. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Sockets != WebSockets

Comment: Thanks the error code is 0, but I figured I am not getting incomplete data but data is fragmented. Now, I am really stuck on how to unmask fragmented data. I can get the first frame unamsked but unable to mask the next frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution to this problem is as follows

**Issue:** When receiving long bytes of data using websocket with something like  `socket_recv($socket,$buffer,5000,0);` you may not get the complete data in single call and you need to call `socket_recv($socket,$buffer,5000,0);` again.

For example, lets suppose we sent 8000 bytes of data from browser to websocket with JS (socket.send). On server side we will use socket_recv to get the message. But we may only receive about 4000 bytes of data first and may need to call socket_recv again to get the remaining 4000 bytes.

Now in my original code I used to call the function "unmask" right after calling socket_recv to unmask the data. This would work for the first set of message received. But for the next set of message the "unmask" function would try to extract new Mask and apply that. This was the error since the message is continuation of previous message and Mask does not change. The solution is to keep the mask from first message and check if next message is continuation or not. This can be done by checking first bit of message.

```
$fin=ord($payload[0]) & 0x77;
```

if $fin is 1 the message is a new message if not it is continuation of previous message. In case of ($fin!=1) you need to use mask of your previous message to unmask the message. Don't forget, since you need to to use the value of mask again you need to define it outside the function and make it global.

I have provided the old and new code below for your reference. I hope this is the right solution but please feel free to add anything or let me know if I went wrong anywhere.

**My Original Unmask function:**

```
function unmask($payload) {
    $length = ord($payload[1]) & 127;
    if($length == 126) {
        $masks = substr($payload, 4, 4);
        $data = substr($payload, 8);
        $firstcode=substr($payload, 1, 1);
    }


    elseif($length == 127) {
        $masks = substr($payload, 10, 4);
        $data = substr($payload, 14);
        $firstcode=substr($payload, 1, 1);

        }
    else {
        $masks = substr($payload, 2, 4);
        $data = substr($payload, 6);
        $firstcode=substr($payload, 1, 1);

    }
    $text = '';
for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($data); ++$i) {
        $text .= $data[$i] ^ $masks[$i%4];
    }

    return $text;
}
```

**Updated Function :**

```
function unmask($payload,$masks) {
global $masks;
$fin=ord($payload[0]) & 0x77;

if($fin!=1){    
    $data=substr($payload,0);
     $text='';
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($data); ++$i) {
        $text .= $data[$i] ^ $masks[$i%4];
    }
    return $text;
}else{
    $length = ord($payload[1]) & 127;

    Echo "Mask functiion Payload Lenght".$length."\n";


    if($length == 126) {
        $masks = substr($payload, 4, 4);
        $data = substr($payload, 8);
    }


    elseif($length == 127) {
        $masks = substr($payload, 10, 4);
        $data = substr($payload, 14);

        }
    else {
        $masks = substr($payload, 2, 4);
        $data = substr($payload, 6);

    }
    $text = '';
for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($data); ++$i) {
        $text .= $data[$i] ^ $masks[$i%4];
    }   
    return $text;
}

}
```