# PHP Webscoekt, Reading fragmented socket messages

Tags: php, websocket

I have the following code to unmask the message sent by browser to server using Websocket. I dont understand much of it but this does not take into account if frame is continuous or last frame.

How can I determine if the frame is continues. I understand the way to do this is read first bit [FIN] of the message but I am unable to find a way to do that. Please help me.

```
function unmask($payload) {
    $length = ord($payload[1]) & 127;
    if($length == 126) {
        $masks = substr($payload, 4, 4);
        $data = substr($payload, 8);
        $firstcode=substr($payload, 1, 1);
    }


    elseif($length == 127) {
        $masks = substr($payload, 10, 4);
        $data = substr($payload, 14);
        $firstcode=substr($payload, 1, 1);

        }
    else {
        $masks = substr($payload, 2, 4);
        $data = substr($payload, 6);
        $firstcode=substr($payload, 1, 1);

    }
    $text = '';
for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($data); ++$i) {
        $text .= $data[$i] ^ $masks[$i%4];
    }

    return $text;
}
```

Comment: Here is the solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41778794/php-websocket-receiving-incomplete-data

Answer (score 0):

When recieving message from browser it is possible that you may not get the packates as inteneded. After several test. The browser can send the data by grouping mutipple messages or split a single message in chunks.

It appears the we need to keep that in mind while unmasking the data on server end. You can make a note of following points.

1. Make sure you recieved all the data, if not call recieve an concate
   the messages in the order they arrive.
2. Unmask the message if you recieved all the data,
3. Use the payload length frame to see how much data is expected.
4. You may also receive multiple messages together. In that case you
   need to spilt the data in smaller chunks and unmask each one
   seperately.

I am not sure if I am able to put my points across but I sincerely hope this helps.